# How to add two properties from the same object in an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, function, object

```js
let aboutMark = {
  firstName: "Mark",
  lastName: "Miller",
  height: 1.69,
  weight: 78,
  bmiCalculator: function(){
    this.markBMI = (this.weight / (this.height * this.height)) 
    return  this.markBMI
  }
};
aboutMark.bmiCalculator()
console.log(aboutMark);
```

What i want to do here is inside aboutMark object i want to add an property and i want the values  to be equal to firstName + lastName.
How do we do it.

Comment: btw, why a property which reflects the first name? why not take an independent propery, like `bmi`?

Comment: You can use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a value after the `object` was made.

```
aboutMark['fullName'] = aboutMark.firstName + " " + aboutMark.lastName;
```

Or make a dynamic function and call it using `console.log(aboutMark.fullName())`

```
let aboutMark = {
    firstName: "Mark",
    lastName: "Miller",
    height: 1.69,
    weight: 78,
    bmiCalculator: function(){
        this.markBMI = (this.weight / (this.height * this.height))
        return  this.markBMI
    },
    fullName: function(){
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
    }
};
```

You can also use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), Thanks [@Nick Parsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648954/nick-parsons)

```
let aboutMark = {
    firstName: "Mark",
    lastName: "Miller",
    height: 1.69,
    weight: 78,
    bmiCalculator: function(){
        this.markBMI = (this.weight / (this.height * this.height))
        return  this.markBMI
    },
    get fullName(){
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
    }
};
```

Comment: The second option won't work because `this` inside of the IIFE will be the global object (`window` in nonstrict browser code). You're better off using a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

Comment: Tested it in `Node.js` seems to be returning the correct output @NickParsons

Comment: @SamHoque I tested in stackoverflow code snippet,and it won't work

Comment: Also tested it in nodejs, the second option doesn't work there either, unless you populate the global scope with `firstName` and `lastName` variables.